# Getting citizenship of a country with which Pakistan do not have dual citizenship agreement.

Tags: pakistani-citizen, multiple-citizenship

Can someone tell me please what happens if a Pakistani gets citizenship of a country with which Pakistan do not have agreement for dual citizenship . Does such person have to give up up Pakistani citizenship ? and what will happen if this person travels to Pakistan with both passports ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Pakistani Nationality Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistani_nationality_law):

> s. 14 If you hold a citizenship outside of Pakistan the Pakistani citizenship is terminated
>
> - Unless one decides to renounce the other
> - Unless one has citizenship in Britain or its colonies
> - Unless one is a female married to a man who is not a Pakistani citizen

and

> s. 14A If a person pledges allegiance or becomes a citizen of another country they have forfeited their Pakistani citizenship
>
> - The exception is if a child (under the age of 21) who does not have his Pakistani citizenship and would like to resume it after turning 21 is allowed to do so.

Additionally (this is probably where the "agreement for dual citizenship" you refer to comes from):

> Dual citizenship is allowed in certain specified circumstances:
>
> - where the citizen who is acquiring the second nationality is under the age of 21
> - where the citizen is also a British citizen
> - where citizens have acquired United States or Swedish nationality

Comment: [This page](http://www.dgip.gov.pk/files/immigration.aspx#IV) from the government of Pakistan mentions "Government of Pakistan has dual nationality arrangements with following 18 countries."

Comment: @user102008 Thanks, that's a great list.

Comment: Still would like to know what will happen if i will go to Pakistan with passport of a country with whome Pakistan do not have dual citizenship agreement.

Comment: Isn't the general rule that a citizen of country X, or a dual citizen of X and another country, should travel in and out of country X on the X passport? If that's so, why should Pakistan even know about the dual citizenship?

Comment: @David: A country is free to make whatever rules they like for their own citizens. Whether the country can practically enforce those rules is another matter.

Comment: @GregHewgill Of course, I do agree. My point was only that if a citizen of Pakistan entered and exited Pakistan using a Pakistani passport, then it was far from certain that Pakistan would even know of the other passport or dual citizenship. However, I must add that I'm not at all displeased this is absent from my personal "That's interesting, I must try it." list.

Comment: @David They can find out. Pakistan requires an immigration exit check where they check if you have a visa/documents for your destination. Pakistan hasn't revoked citizenship since 2002. In a report published by the Election Commission of Pakistan about Pakistan election candidates (https://www.ecp.gov.pk/FIA%20ECP%20report.pdf) shows one candidate also has an Uzbek passport (which isn't covered by the 19 countries rule). Nobody is talking about revoking his citizenship! Only that he is ineligible to contest elections because he is a dual national. So what's the law?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I am trying to find the answer to this as well.

On the face of it, the law says (Pakistan Citizenship Act 1951)

> Subject to the provisions of this
>   section if any person is a citizen of Pakistan under the provisions of this Act, and is at the same
>   time a citizen or national of any other country he shall, unless he makes a declaration according
>   to the laws of that other country renouncing his status as citizen or national thereof, cease to be a
>   citizen of Pakistan

However, the courts had their own interpretation of the Act.

This case in the Sindh High Court refers to Umar Ahmed Ghumman v. Government of
Pakistan (PLD 2002 Lah 521) (which I can't seem to get a hold of). This is before the Federal Government included USA in the allowed list.

> The petitioner in that case was admittedly a dual
>   citizen of Pakistan and USA and was aggrieved of a two-fold finding of
>   the Election Commission of Pakistan against him, viz. (a) that by
>   virtue of section 14(1) of the Pakistan Citizenship Act, 1951, he had
>   ceased to be a Pakistani citizen; and (b) that by virtue of Article
>   63(1)(c) of the Constitution of the Islamic Republic of Pakistan, 1973,
>   he was disqualified from contesting election to Parliament. After a very
>   informative discourse on the concepts of citizenship, nationality and
>   dual nationality, the Court held essentially that section 14 when read
>   with section 14-A of the Pakistan Citizenship Act, 1951, shows that the
>   disqualification in section 14(1) of the said Act is not automatic but
>   comes into play only when the competent authority of the other
>   country requires the Pakistani citizen to renounce his Pakistani
>   citizenship as a condition to the grant of nationality of that other
>   country, or where the Pakistani citizen voluntary renounces his
>   Pakistani citizenship to acquire another citizenship.

If a citizen of Pakistan was allowed to have a second citizenship of any other country that does not require him/her to renounce his Pakistani citizenship, why is there a need for bilateral agreements that allow this with (now) 19 countries?